# anyDensity on Android manifest ,

Tags: android, android-manifest, device, manifest, android-screen-support

i Have following code on my manifest

```
 <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

the problem is my application isnt visible to ldpi devices, And i want to make it visible .
I have read all about anydensity on net, and if change it to true it is not running on ldpi device because i am creating bitmap in my apps, 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: may be you can provide crash stack trace? Is it ResourceNotFound exception?

Answer (score 0):

Why use this tag in manifest? Do you or do you not want you app to be available on ldpi devices?

Comment: if i didnt use this tag then my application will be crashed on ldpi device

Comment: So you did want your app to be compatible with ldpi devices? You might want post your code and error log here.

Comment: my application is runnig fine with above support tag, but if i remove above tag then it crashes, and above tag would not allow my application visible to ldpi devices. @KorniltsevAnatoly

Comment: That's wired, 'cause `<supports-screens>` tag and `<compatible-screens>` are supposed to be used by external services like google play to filter apps.

Answer (score 0):

ldpi devices constitute only 1.7% of the devices on Google Play. This [statistic](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) dates back from the week of October 1, 2012. It's probably much lower by now.

Personally, I don't know anyone who still owns an ldpi device, except for myself. And I wouldn't be surprised if the only ldpi devices remaining active on Google Play are owned by developers like me, who kept them initially just for testing purposes.

[image]

What would be the point of rewriting your app for those devices? Are those users more likely to spend money on your app? Are those users more likely to watch more advertisements than other users? On the contrary.

Even if you do a good job rewriting your app for that super tiny sliver of the market, the user experience resulting will be so  degraded, it probably won't be worth installing your app on those types of phones.

Comment: Well Said , i agree with you, but i am still curious about the subject why this all is happening.